# Problems inserting value into matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I am trying to insert a value into Matlab vector like this:

```
 P = [ P(1:pos) point P(pos+1:end-1) ];
```

Yet I keep getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> main at 65
 P = [ P(1:pos) point P(pos+1:end-1) ];
```

There is `end-1` because I red that error above have something to do with arrays limits mismatch.

P.S. I know that value insertion into arrays is pretty common issue yet this seams to be the simplest way to do it and I really would like to understand why it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is attempting to concatenate horizontally

```
P = [ P(1:pos) point P(pos+1:end-1) ]
```

But your vector P is a column vector.

What you need is a row vector, so transpose P first

```
P=P';
```

Comment: It is sufficient to cat vertically then, using ;

Comment: @Acrobe, yes P=vertcat(P(1:pos), point, P(pos+1:end-1)), but my personal taste would be to use the easiest statement to type which is to use the [] syntax.

Comment: @jerad, well, indeed I ment something way easier like `P = [P(...) ; p ; P(...)]`..;)